# Ember.js two API's same resource name

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**ember 3.3**

**Desired outcome**: To have two models available; "bc-theme" and "ra-theme" in ember pulled from two different API's that use the resource name "theme".

I have a simple way of normalizing/serializing the model name for one "rename" but have not found a way to determine the rename based on what API it's requested from and thus be able to rename appropriately. As you can see from the provided code, the mappings will fail if I introduce another "theme" because their will be duplicate keys on the mapping for normalization.

Without the extra theme the mappings work as expected.

Is there some way to see what adapter is being used in the serializer? Or since it's being request by an ember findRecord and via relationships could the theme "type" be determined some other way on each request?

The backends are written in Ruby on Rails and can be modified as well, but it seems like ember should be the one to handle the differences since the API's are independent of one another.

```js
// adapters/ra-theme.js
import RaAdapter from './ra';

export default RaAdapter.extend({
  pathForType() {
    return this._super('themes');
  }
});

// adapters/bc-theme.js
import bcAdapter from './bc';

export default bcAdapter.extend({
  pathForType() {
    return this._super('themes');
  }
});


// serializers/application.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

const keysMappingForSerialization = {
  'bc-theme': 'theme',
  ...
};
const keysMappingForNormalization = {
  'theme': 'bc-theme',
  ...
};

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
  payloadKeyFromModelName(key) {
    if (keysMappingForSerialization[key]) {
      return this._super(keysMappingForSerialization[key]);
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  },
  modelNameFromPayloadKey(modelName) {
    if (keysMappingForNormalization[modelName]) {
      return this._super(keysMappingForNormalization[modelName]);
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }

});

// serializers/bc-theme-group.js
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';

const keysForRelationshipsMapping = {
  'bcThemes': 'themes'
};

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  keyForRelationship(key) {
    if (keysForRelationshipsMapping[key]) {
      return this._super(keysForRelationshipsMapping[key]);
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }
});

// serializers/bc-theme.js
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';

const keysForRelationshipsMapping = {
  'bcThemeGroups': 'themeGroups'
};

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend({
  keyForRelationship(key) {
    if (keysForRelationshipsMapping[key]) {
      return this._super(keysForRelationshipsMapping[key]);
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you use store.adapterFor(modelName) in the serializer? Takes a string.

Comment: @Gaurav Yes I could inject the store as a service, but I don't think this will provide the info for the "current" adapter well enough, since if I pass in "theme" dynamically from the key or model name it still won't be able to know what type of theme to reverse name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is rather simple.

I was able to accomplish this by serializing and normalizing on model specific serializers/adapters. By not going through the top level application serializer it would map what's needed only when the appropriate serializer was run.

So while it duplicates some code, it accomplishes what's needed in my case.

EDIT:
Here is the refactored code.

```js
// mixins/model-rename.js
import Mixin from '@ember/object/mixin';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Mixin.create({
  mappingForSerialization(acronym) {
    let mapName = acronym + 'KeysMappingForSerialization';
    return this.get(mapName);
  },
  mappingForNormalization(acronym) {
    let mapName =  acronym + 'KeysMappingForNormalization';
    return this.get(mapName);
  },

  bcKeysMappingForSerialization: computed('acronym', function() {
    return {
      'bc-theme-group': 'theme-group',
      'bc-theme': 'theme'
    };
  }),

  bcKeysMappingForNormalization: computed('acronym', function() {
    return {
      'theme-group': 'bc-theme-group',
      'theme': 'bc-theme'
    };

  }),

  radioKeysMappingForSerialization: computed('acronym', function() {
    return {
      'radio-theme': 'theme',
      'radio-tag': 'tag',
    };

  }),
  radioKeysMappingForNormalization: computed('acronym', function() {
    return {
      'theme': 'radio-theme',
      'tag': 'radio-tag'
    };
  }),

  keyForRelationship(key) {
    if (this.keysForRelationshipsMapping[key]) {
      return this._super(this.keysForRelationshipsMapping[key]);
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  },

  payloadKeyFromModelName(key) {
    if (this.mappingForSerialization(this.get('acronym'))[key]) {
      return this._super(this.mappingForSerialization(this.get('acronym'))[key]);
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  },
  modelNameFromPayloadKey(modelName) {
    if (this.mappingForNormalization(this.get('acronym'))[modelName]) {
      return this._super(this.mappingForNormalization(this.get('acronym'))[modelName]);
    } else {
      return this._super(...arguments);
    }
  }
});

// serializers/bc-theme-group.js
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';
import modelRename from '../mixins/model-rename';

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(modelRename, {
  acronym: 'bc',

  keysForRelationshipsMapping(key) {
    let mapping =  {
      'bcThemes': 'themes'
    }
    return mapping[key];
  }

});



// serializers/bc-theme.js
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';
import modelRename from '../mixins/model-rename';

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(modelRename, {
  acronym: 'bc',

  keysForRelationshipsMapping(key) {
    let mapping =  {
      'bcThemeGroups': 'themeGroups',
    }
    return mapping[key];
  }

});

// serializers/radio-theme.js
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';
import modelRename from '../mixins/model-rename';

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(modelRename, {
  acronym: 'radio',
});


// It's also important to note that any other models that are related to the changes would also need the mappings

// serializers/episode.js
import ApplicationSerializer from './application';
import modelRename from '../mixins/model-rename';

export default ApplicationSerializer.extend(modelRename, {
  acronym: 'radio',

  keysForRelationshipsMapping(key) {
    let mapping =  {
      'radioTheme': 'theme',
      'radioTags': 'tags'
    }
    return mapping[key];
  }

});
```